# How to capture DOM Explorer with CSharp

Tags: javascript, c#, internet-explorer, dom, webbrowser-control

In Internet Explorer, F12 gives access to two tabs: DOM Explorer and DEBUGGER.

Both of these tabs have different contents but I do not yet know what their distinction is.

I want to capture the DOM Explorer data, not the DEBUGGER information of a webpage.

When I use either of the following two pieces of code I capture the information found in the DEBUGGER, my question is: How do I capture the DOM EXPLORER data so that I can run REGEX?

CODE 1:

```
            string urlAddress = "https://www.goodgaragescheme.com/pages/map.aspx?loc=CO70AN";

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader readStream = null;

                if (response.CharacterSet == null)
                {
                    readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
                }
                else
                {
                    readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
                }

                string data = readStream.ReadToEnd();

                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"FILENAME.txt", data);

                response.Close();
                readStream.Close();
            }
```

CODE 2:

```
        using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            var content = client.DownloadString("https://www.goodgaragescheme.com/pages/map.aspx?loc=CO70AN");

            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"FILENAME.txt", content);
        }
```

Comment: It sounds like you actually want to run a headless browser.

Comment: It can be headless, I just need access to the DOM explorer text rather than the DEBUGGER text. Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
        SHDocVw.InternetExplorer IE = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
        IE.Visible = false;
        IE.Navigate(@"https://www.goodgaragescheme.com/pages/map.aspx?loc=CO70AN");

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

        mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 htmlDoc = IE.Document as mshtml.IHTMLDocument2;
        string content = htmlDoc.body.outerHTML;

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"FILENAME.txt", content);
        System.Console.WriteLine("done");
        System.Console.ReadKey();
```

Persistence FTW.